# Run express app in dev with port listener and export app with Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have an express app with dev mode with listener on port. But for Cloud Functions I need to export app with https.onRequest. Is it ok to make it with if condition?

```
  ...
  .use(router)
  .use(ErrorHandler);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() == 'development') {
  app.listen(config.DEV_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Webserver started. Port ${config.DEV_PORT} is listening...`);
    console.log(`Hosting URL: http://localhost:${config.DEV_PORT}/`);
  });
} else {
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
}
```

It's working well without condition but I don't know what is happening with this app.listen on firebase server after deploy. Is it listening something? Is it using memory?

I would be very thankful for some explaining.

```
  ...
  .use(router)
  .use(ErrorHandler);

 app.listen(config.DEV_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Webserver started. Port ${config.DEV_PORT} is listening...`);
    console.log(`Hosting URL: http://localhost:${config.DEV_PORT}/`);
  });
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For http type functions, Cloud Functions infrastructure listens for you, and it forwards any incoming requests to your express app. That's the way serverless products work - server instances that handle your function may scale up or down to handle the load, so the system has to do the listening for you (even if you have 0 instances running).  It's not possible to listen in your own code (because you might only have 0 instances running, and nothing of yours would be listening).